# How do i print a line diagonally in python3? I would like to print the letter A. I am a new user to python

Tags: python-3.6

I would like to print the letter A. I am a new user to python. I am trying to use the following piece of code. How can i improve this?

letter_rep=['******']

for i in range(len(letter_rep)):

```
print('*'*i,letter_rep)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The shape of letter A made of `*`?

Comment: yes. I would like to make the shape of letter A using '*' @ FranchenBao

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_A(w: int, h: int, char: str) -> None:
    """Print the letter 'A' as an ASCII art using char.

    Play around with w and h to find the ideal dimenstion. A good starting
    point can be w = 20, h = 10

    :param w: Width of the canvas
    :param h: Height of the canvas
    :param char: Character used for the ASCII art.
    """
    # Let the north west point of the canvas be the origin, we can generate
    # the equations to compute the x coordinate based on the current y for the
    # left and right strokes of the letter 'A'
    left_stroke = lambda y: int((y + h) * w / (2 * h))
    right_stroke = lambda y: int((h - y) * w / (2 * h))
    mid_stroke_y: int = h // 2  # Set position of the horizontal stroke
    for y in range(h):
        # must use negative y due to the canvas being in the fourth quadrant
        left_stroke_x = left_stroke(-y)
        right_stroke_x = right_stroke(-y)
        # The following print statements can be condensed to one line. 
        # It is expanded here for better explanation.
        print(' ' * left_stroke_x, end='')  # Empty spaces to the left of the left stroke
        print(char, end='')  # Left stroke
        print(  # Space between the left and right stroke
            (right_stroke_x - left_stroke_x) * (char if y == mid_stroke_y else ' '), 
            end='',
        )
        print(char, end='')  # Right stroke
        print(' ' * (w - right_stroke_x))  # Empty spaces to the right of the right stroke
```

Example usage:

```
print_A(20, 10, '*')
'''
Output:

          **          
         *  *         
        *    *        
       *      *       
      *        *      
     ************     
    *            *    
   *              *   
  *                *  
 *                  * 

'''

print_A(40, 10, '@')
'''
Output:
                    @@                    
                  @    @                  
                @        @                
              @            @              
            @                @            
          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@          
        @                        @        
      @                            @      
    @                                @    
  @                                    @  
'''
```

Comment: Hey thanks @FranchenBao. That is quite a lot of code for a beginner like myself. But nevertheless I will have to use what you have shared with me to become more proficient using python3. I appreciate the help.

Comment: This piece of code works just excellent!!!. Thanks again @FranchenBao. I have to study the syntax line by line to understand it better.

Comment: You are welcome. The syntax was indeed dense for a beginner, but I hope it was a good stimulus for you to explore further.